# jQuery: Submit with input name

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I have a `<form id="foo" action="bar.php" method="post">` that has 2 submit buttons, `name="save"` and `name="lock"`.

I'm running a jquery function:

```
$("a#submit").click(function() {
    $("#foo").submit();
});
```

How can I tell jQuery to submit the name `lock` and not the other one?

Comment: `$("input[name='lock']").click();` why cant you use this?

Comment: Addition to above comment, better use `$("input[name='lock']")[0].click();`

Comment: One form can only have one action, do you mean you want to click `name` button then go to action 1, click `lock` button then go to action 2?

Comment: The link that I want to use to trigger the form submit is not within the form, which is why I cannot use click(). I want the link to submit a form on the page. But that form has 2 `<input type="submit">`, one has a name of `save` and the other has `lock`. I want to trigger the lock one.

Answer (score 1):

Save the form by ajax method . You want to save the form with two submit button.
For 1 button call the ajax & save. Second button will work as usual.

```
 $("input[name='lock']").click(function({
       $.ajax({
          url: 'test.php',
          type:'POST',              
          data: $("#fo").serialize();
        })
 }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could trigger a click-event on the button:

```
$("a#submit").click(function() {
    $( "button[name=lock]" ).trigger( "click" );
});
```